# Isuue with my dependency having dependencies (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a repository class that looks as following:

```
public class StationsRepository : IStationsRepository
    {
        private readonly AftermarketDbContext _db;

        public StationsRepository(DbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
```

and in my startup.cs class i have added it to services as following.

```
 services.AddTransient<IStationsRepository, StationsRepository>();
```

And in my controller I have injected it as following:

```
public RpcApiController(AftermarketDbContext db,IStationsRepository stationsRepository)
        {
            _db = db;
            _stationsRepository = stationsRepository;
        }
```

But my issue is how do I use it when I need it in the controller because it needs a database to be sent to the constructor so where so I do that? What would a example of using the repositories "GetStation" method look like for example?

Comment: Why do you need DbContext in your Controller? You should stick to repository (if you don't have services).

Comment: its a long and old legacy code that I'm trying to refractor but it is proving to be a real pain. I cant remove the Db from there. And i do have services.

Comment: Could you then clarify you problem a bit? What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I don't understand how to and when to insert the DB object into the Repository constructor if it is added to services if that makes any sense.

Comment: You already added the "DB object" in the repository constructor. Can you elaborate more? Your question/problem is too vague, unfortunately.

Comment: [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) will do that for you, you don't have to worry about it. You've already added the repository to DI container with `AddTransient` method. The only place you would need to do it manually is in unit tests, but there you just pass objects around, e.g. `new Repository(new DbContext())`.

Comment: Thats all i wanted to know. Thank you.